# Huffman compression reading file does not copy all the bytes in the binary file c++

Tags: c++, huffman-code

My program is Huffman compression, everything is working great, except for one annoying thing.
When I read bytes from the compressed file only approximately a third of the bytes get copied, and decompressed (goes back to normal text).
I really don't know where the problem is.
Here is the function the reads the bytes from the file and returns it to an STL container:

```
template<class Container>
Container readcompressfile(string ifileloc) {
    ifstream ifile(ifileloc);

    if (!ifile) {
        throw runtime_error("Could not open " + ifileloc + " for reading");
    }

    noskipws(ifile);

    return Container(istream_iterator<uint8_t>(ifile), istream_iterator<uint8_t>());
}
```

And here is how I'm calling it in my decompression function(that calls another function that I included under it, if its important) (in a class):

```
void decompressfile(string loc) {
        vector<uint8_t> vecbytes(readcompressfile<vector<uint8_t>>(ifilelocation)); // Here is where I'm using the above function

        vector<uint8_t>::iterator iter = vecbytes.begin();

        uint8_t ctr = 0xFF;
        bitset<8> b2 = 0;
        string code = "";

        for (; iter != vecbytes.end(); ++iter) {
            b2 = ctr & *iter;

            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
                code += to_string(b2[i]);
            }
        }

        decodetext(code, loc);
    }

    //Reads bits and outputs string
    void decodetext(string codetext, string ofileloc) {
        string code = "";
        string text = "";
        char lett;

        for each (char ct in codetext) {
            code += ct;
            lett = returncharmap(code);
            if (lett != NULL) {
                text += lett;
                code = "";
            }
        }

        ofstream ofile(ofileloc);
        ofile << text;
        ofile.close();
    }
```

The compressing function turns a String of 1's and 0's to bits (I package them into bytes) and then store it in the file (that is working fine), as for the decompression as you've noticed I read the binary file in the `readcompressfile(string ifileloc)` function and then place it in `vector<uint8_t>` container and then turn it back into a String of 1's and 0's and again back to text, and the bytes that get copied get decompressed fine.

[I displayed the size of the string before and after and here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtcRB.png)

Note: The `readcompressfile(string ifileloc)` function i copied from someone on stackoverflow because it solved a problem I had earlier.

Comment: Instead of `std::istream_iterator` you might wan to consider [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) instead. Then you don't have to worry about "whitespace" at least.

Comment: I used it but didnt work, it was giving me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running on Windows, which will interpret a `^Z` character in a text stream (which is the default mode for an `ifstream`) as an end-of-file indicator.

Instead of:

```
 ifstream ifile(ifileloc);
```

use:

```
 ifstream ifile(ifileloc, ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
```

As pointed out in comments below, the Windows platform will also transform  the `"\r\n"` character sequence into a single character `"\n"` in text mode.

Comment: That's not the only problem on Windows, mor commonly is the newline conversion (`"\r\n"` to `"\n"`).

Comment: True enough - that should have been mentioned.  The large difference in sizes in the example posted (which should have been copy/pasted into the question as text) made me go right to EOF.

Comment: Actually that was the problem, thank you now its working perfectly